# Spring stomp. Close session on SessionConnectedEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stomp

I use `spring-boot-starter-websocket` and have event listener on SessionConnectedEvent.

```
@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
    log.debug("SessionConnectedEvent: {}", event);
    ...
}
```

There I check a header and I want close/invalidate session if header don't contain correct data. How I can do it? May be I can get session object or I should use some HandshakeHandler?

Comment: If the scenario is similar to token based authentication for WebSocket, it is suggested to authenticate the user with OncePerRequestFilter. Please refer to https://medium.com/swlh/spring-boot-security-jwt-hello-world-example-b479e457664c as an example.